# In Apache Spark Sql Context how to delete rows with same ID but different row values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, duplicates

In Spark I have DataFrame like this

```
ID  AGE INFO
2    21  123
2    21  245
3    24  125
3    24  55 
3    24  256
4    26  245
5    21  22
```

As you can see first two rows share same ID "2" but have different INFO. Same thing with row3,4 and 5.(They share ID 3 but contain different INFO) What I want is only keep the row with Unique ID and smallest INFO number. So the output should be like this

```
ID  AGE INFO
2    21  123
3    24  55 
4    26  245
5    21  22
```

I think it can be easier to do it with SQL Context, however, if you have solution to do this directly with DataFrame, it will also be helpful! Thanks! (I asked this as a SQl question first, and someone suggest me to ask it with Spark tag. So I modify my question and hope it will be a more clear one) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply group and aggregate:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.min

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (2, 21,  123), (2, 21,  245), (3, 24,  125),
    (3, 24,  55), (3, 24,  256),(4, 26,  245), (5, 21,  22)
)).toDF("ID", "AGE", "INFO")

val transformed1 = df.groupBy($"ID", $"AGE").agg(min($"INFO").alias("INFO"))
```

Using raw SQL:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
val transformed2 = sqlContext.sql(
  "SELECT id, age, min(info) info FROM df GROUP BY id, age")
```